# $ a+b+c=0,\ a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ implies $ a^4+b^4+c^4=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, riemannian-geometry, convex-geometry

This is a high school problem. It is solved by algebraic calculation
(not difficult) - $\ast$.

But I have a problem in interpretation the result.

Here intersection of two surfaces $a+b+c=0,\ a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ is a
circle $C$. That is, by $\ast$, $a^4+b^4+c^4$ is constant on it. **What does make
it so ?**

Proof : Note that $S:=\{
(a,b,c)|a^4+b^4+c^4=\frac{1}{2}\}$ is a convex surface. In further,
there is $x,\ y\in S$ s.t. $|x|<1<|y|$.

And I guess that $C$ is not a geodesic : Consider a norm on $\mathbb{R}^3$. For instance $\| (a,b,c) \|_1 := |a|+|b|+|c|$ In this case unit ball wrt this norm is octahedron. In further, unit balls of standard Euclidean norm, infinite norm are unit sphere $S_2$, a cube $S_3$, respectively. Clearly, intersection of $S_2$ and plane $\{ (a,b,c)| a+b+c=0\}$ is a geodesic (So is $S_3$). Here considering $S$ and $S_3$, we can assume that $S$ is like $S_3$. That is, $S$ has largest Gaussian curvature at eight points. Hence geodesic is far from these points, but $C$ is not.

I enumerate some these exercises, but how can we interpret the answer ?

**[add]** Consider $ \Delta':=\{ (x,y,z)\in S_2 | x,\ y,\ z\geq 0\} $, which
is an equilateral geodesic triangle of side length $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

In further $\Delta \subset \Delta'$ is also an equilateral geodesic
triangle of side length $\frac{\pi}{3}$, which touches mid points of
sides in $\Delta'$. Clearly it is not in a plane.

Then we have a **claim** that if $ f (x,y,z)=(x^4,y^4 ,z^4)$, then
$f(\partial \Delta )$ is in a plane.

[my answer] Consider $SO(3)$-action on $S^2(1)$. Here what is $smallest$ invariant set ? It is $S^2$. Consider a finite subgroup of $SO(3)$. For instance, a group $H$ which acts on cube whose center is origin. So smallest invariant set of $H$ is not $S^2$. It may be union of finite number of great circles, $T$. And note that $F(x,y,z)=x^4+y^4+z^4$ is invariant under $H$. Hence we can guess that $F$ is constant on $T$.

Comment: Being a circle doesn't immediately imply that $a^4 + b^4 + c^4$ should be a constant - at least I don't see how it should.

Comment: @DavidQuinn I'm fairly certain $C$ is the intersection of the two surfaces, which would make it a circle.

Comment: @DavidQuinn He says the intersection of the plane and the sphere is a circle.

Comment: @B. Mehta : $0=(a+b+c)^2=1 +2(ab+bc+ca)$ So $1=(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2=a^4+b^4+c^4 + 2\cdot \frac{1}{4}$

Comment: Why do you say $C$ is not a geodesic?  It's the intersection of a plane through the origin with a sphere centered at the origin.

Comment: @HKLee I agree it certainly is true, but that's a consequence of the equations given, not a direct consequence of the intersection being a circle.

Comment: @saulspatz : I add more explanation.

Comment: @B. Mehta : You are right. I edited.

Comment: A kind of explanation is given by [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities). They allow us to write power sums in terms of elementary symmetric polynomials. When the sum of first powers vanishes (as is the case here), then the  effect of the third elementary symmetric polynomial disappears (it is multiplied by the sum of first powers), and the fourth elementary symmetric polynomial doesn't appear because you only have three variables. So the two coincidences at play are 1) $a+b+c$ is precisely zero, and 2) there are only three variables.

Comment: (cont'd) But, the Newton identities are exactly the calculations in Lab's and Sonnhard's answers. It may also possible to give a statistical interpretation of this in terms of moments of coordinates of a random point on that circle of intersection, but I'm not sure that would shed additional light either.

Answer (score 8):

HINT:

From the identity
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2-2(a^4+b^4+c^4)=(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)$$

the equality $a^4+b^4+c^4=1/2$ is a consequence of $a+b+c=0$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$. One can also look at gradients and see a geometric reason from the equality.

Note that conversely $a^4+b^4+c^4=1/2$ and $a+b+c=0$ implies $(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2=1$ and so (reals!) $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$. So indeed the plane cuts the surface along that circle.

One can cook up different surfaces of equation
$$P(a,b,c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-1)+Q(a,b,c)(a+b+c)=0$$ that will contain the same circle.

If one looks at the surface $a^4+b^4+c^4=1/2$, it has the shape of a rounded cube. How is it that the plane $a+b+c=0$ cuts it along a circle?

Recall that a cube $\max(|a|,|b|,|c|)=1$ is cut by this plane along a regular hexagon with vertices the permutations of $(-1,0,1)$. Now the permutations of $(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 0, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ lie on both of the surfaces $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ and $a^4+b^4+c^4=\frac{1}{2}$. That should make it more intuitive.

Note that each of the $4$ planes $a\pm b\pm c = 0$ cuts our surface along a circle, as the identity tells us.

Comment: Where does this identity come from?

Comment: @Addem;  It's an alternate  formula for  the area of the triangle.

Comment: @Addem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula

Answer (score 6):

The geometric approach that you have outlined...

The intersection of $a+b+c = 0$ and $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1$

A plane cutting a sphere, producing a circle.

$a^4 + b^4 + c^4 = \frac 12$ is a convex surface that resembles a cube with rounded edges and corners.

As it happens every point on the circle $C$ lies on this "cubeoid."  But, it is still not obvious that this would be the case.

You could parameterize the circle:

$\begin {bmatrix} 
\frac {\sqrt 3}{3} & \frac {\sqrt 2}{2} &\frac {\sqrt 6}{6}\\
\frac {\sqrt 3}{3} & -\frac {\sqrt 2}{2} &\frac {\sqrt 6}{6}\\
\frac {\sqrt 3}{3} & 0 &-\frac {\sqrt 6}{3}\end{bmatrix}\begin {bmatrix} 0\\\cos\theta\\\sin\theta\end{bmatrix}= \begin {bmatrix} \frac {\sqrt 2}{ 2}\cos\theta + \frac {\sqrt {6}}{6}\sin\theta\\-\frac {\sqrt 2}{ 2}\cos\theta + \frac {\sqrt {6}}{6}\sin\theta\\-\frac {\sqrt 6}{3}\sin\theta\end{bmatrix}$

Would give you a parameterization of the circle.

And $a^4 +b^4 + c^4$ indeed does equal $\frac 12$

I don't think that this is easier than the more algebraic approaches...But it does work.

Answer (score 1):

Addem, we could do like following. (I write here because it's too long in comment).

1.

> $$ a+b+c=0 $$
>   $$ (a+b+c)^2=0 $$
>   $$ a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ac=0 $$
>   $$ a^2+b^2+c^2=−2(ab+bc+ac) $$
>   $$ 1=−2(ab+bc+ac) $$ 
>   $$ ⇒ ab+bc+ac=−\frac{1}{2}. $$

2.

> $$ (ab+bc+ac)^2=a^2b^2+b^2c^2+a^2c^2+2a^2bc+2ab^2c+2abc^2$$
>   $$ (ab+bc+ac)^2=a^2b^2+b^2c^2+a^2c^2+2abc(a+b+c)$$
>   $$ (−\frac{1}{2})^2=a^2b^2+b^2c^2+a^2c^2+0$$
>   $$ ⇒ a^2b^2+b^2c^2+a^2c^2=\frac{1}{4}. $$

3.

> $$ a^2+b^2+c^2=1 $$
>   $$ (a^2+b^2 +c^2)^2=1 $$
>   $$ a^4+b^4+c^4+2a^2b^2+2a^2c^2+2b^2c^2=1 $$
>   $$ a^4+b^4+c^4+2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+a^2c^2)=1 $$
>   $$ a^4+b^4+c^4+2*\frac{1}{4}=1 $$
>   $$ ⇒ a^4+b^4+c^4=\frac{1}{2}. $$

Answer (score 1):

I would propose a more algebraic approach. Two constraints on three variables do not seem enough to fix all three variables, hence give $a^4+b^4+c^4$. On the other hand, if $a,b,c$ are real numbers and $c=-(a+b)$, then
$$ 1 = a^2+b^2+c^2 = 2(a^2+ab+b^2) $$
and
$$ a^4+b^4+c^4 = 2a^4+4a^3b+6a^2 b^2+4ab^3+2b^4=2(a^2+ab+b^2)^2 = 2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:
$$(a+b+c)^2=0 \Rightarrow ab+bc+ca=-\frac12 \Rightarrow (ab)^2+(bc)^2+(ca)^2=\frac14.$$
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2=1 \Rightarrow a^4+b^4+c^4=1-2((ab)^2+(bc)^2+(ca)^2)=1-2\cdot \frac14=\frac12.$$